# High CPU usage (gnome shell, firefox)

Tags: gnome-shell, cpu-load

This is a 4 cores 8 threads cpu machine which i monitor with Htop, Ubuntu 22.04, updated.
Firefox is opened with a LAARRGGE number of windows and tabs (do not ask how many); Thunderbird is running, libreoffice, and a few other programs, all showing below 2% in htop (most below 0.2%, in fact).

with Htop gnome-shell showing typically 45% cpu while overall load is 8-9% and other top processes show an average aggregate ~ 5%
So yes, gnome-shell consumes 10x more than other processes' aggregate cpu usage
Laptop cpu a bit hot and fan constantly > 3000 or 4000 rpm usually after 2-3 days up (all is normally quiet the first 2-3 days after reboot)

It does not look like what is expected (and I do not recall 18.04 was misbehaving this way)
Any thought ?
Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

try type

```
kill -3 $(pidof gnome-shell)
```

. This will restart gnome-shell. Save everything first.

Comment: Tx.  2 comments: 1- CPU drastically came down after closing some page which was creating the high CPU issue, and 2- killing gnome shell proved efficientto bring everything down to normal (and killed everything including my session). Way for efficient than anything else i had tried. Tx a lot